# How to display an JSON array in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, arrays, json

I got this json response and i created an object for nsdictionary and saved there as

```
NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:kNilOptions error:&error];
```

and next step i saved as an array

```
NSArray *country=[json objectForKey:@"results"];
```

And then i got the following result in my console.

```
2012-06-18 09:22:07.647 TableView[468:f803] (
                {
                "Countries" = Iceland;
                 "id"=9046567;
                  "name"=abceeeffdsg;


            },
                {
                "Countries" = Greenland;
                "id"=3524695;
                "name"=gsfjgfsethju;
    },
                {
                 "Countries" = Switzerland;
                 "id"=4613583;
                 "name"=hdfkdgs;
        )
```

But actually i want to display these data in a UITableView. Can anyone help me make my work completed.... thanks for your kindness...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the tableview datasource methods

```
1. numberof RowInSection use the [country count];
2. In the cellForRowAtIndexPath

    cell.textLabel.text = [[country objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Countries"];
```

Let me know if you need any more details.

Comment: ohh thanks but this is not i wanted. can u read the question again i have no trouble in adding rows and row counts to my UITableView. Actually i am not able to get the datas from the json array to my table... and this is not the code for that. can u help me rather than giving -ve marks....

Comment: NSArray *a = [country valueForKey:@"Countries"];

Comment: thank u.... another doubt... i cant access this array outside the     " -(void)fetchedData:(NSData *)responseData" can u help me in this..

Comment: In .h file declare that array, alloc memory in viewdidload and access any where.